# Just wondering why this isn't working, I want to insert data from submit form to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, pdo

I'm trying to send data from my submit form to the database, I'm using phpliteadmin as my database manager.

here is my php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    include('connect-phpliteadmin.php');

$make = $_POST['Make'];
$model = $_POST['Model'];
$badge = $_POST['Badge'];
$price = $_POST['Price'];
$trans = $_POST['Transmission'];
$ppl = $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'];

$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl'");

    if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
        die("Error inserting new vehicle");
    }

    $newrecord = "New record added to the database";

}

echo "Make: " . $_POST['Make'] . "<br>";
echo "Model: " . $_POST['Model'] . "<br>";
echo "Badge: " . $_POST['Badge'] . "<br>";
echo "Price: " . $_POST['Price'] . "<br>";
echo "Transmission: " . $_POST['Transmission'] . "<br>";
echo "P Plate Legal: " . $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'] . "<br>";




try {
  # Connect to SQLite database
  $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:Car_Sales_Network");



  # Prepare SQL statemen
  #$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl'");

  # Run the query on the database
  $sth->execute(array($make, $model));



?>
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working, I have followed a YouTube video and it didn't work. A fix would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: What errors are occurring? Is error reporting on? Could you show us some HTML?

Answer (score 2):

You SQL statement seems incorrect as far as I am aware.

Your query,

```
$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl'");
```

New query,

```
$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make', '$model', '$badge', '$price', '$trans', '$ppl'");
```

As far as I'm aware you can't have `' '` for all the `VALUES`.

Comment: @Zanderwar but doesn't he need to split each one? Not put all variables in one `' ' `.

Answer (score 1):

It should be this:

FROM:

```
$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans,$ppl'");`
```

TO:

```
 $sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make', '$model', '$badge', '$price', '$trans','$ppl'");
```

---

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
 include('connect-phpliteadmin.php');

 $make = $_POST['Make'];
 $model = $_POST['Model'];
 $badge = $_POST['Badge'];
 $price = $_POST['Price'];
 $trans = $_POST['Transmission'];
 $ppl = $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'];

$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make', '$model', '$badge', '$price', '$trans','$ppl'");

  if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert)) {
    die("Error inserting new vehicle");
  }

$newrecord = "New record added to the database";

}

echo "Make: " . $_POST['Make'] . "<br>";
echo "Model: " . $_POST['Model'] . "<br>";
echo "Badge: " . $_POST['Badge'] . "<br>";
echo "Price: " . $_POST['Price'] . "<br>";
echo "Transmission: " . $_POST['Transmission'] . "<br>";
echo "P Plate Legal: " . $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'] . "<br>";




try {
  # Connect to SQLite database
  $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:Car_Sales_Network");



  # Prepare SQL statemen
  #$sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network (Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal) VALUES ('$make', '$model' , '$badge', '$price', '$trans', '$ppl'");

  # Run the query on the database
  $sth->execute(array($make, $model));



?>
```

Comment: Elaborate on your answer: Why should it be this? What have you changed?

Answer (score 0):

In your `INSERT` query you missed `''` for all `variables` and at end missed closing bracket `)`

This is your query

```
$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network
(Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal)
 VALUES 
('$make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl'");
```

It should be like

```
$sqlinsert("INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network 
(Make, Model,  Badge, Price, Transmission, P_Plate_Legal)
 VALUES
('$make', '$model', '$badge', '$price', '$trans', '$ppl')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, for future reference I changed it to this :)

```
<?php

try {
    # Connect to SQLite database
    $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:../Car_Sales_Network");

    $make = $_POST['Make'];
    $model = $_POST['Model'];
    $badge = $_POST['Badge'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $trans = $_POST['Transmission'];
    $ppl = $_POST['P_Plate_Legal'];

    print_r($_POST);

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO Cars_On_Network
                         ("car_make","car_model","car_badge","price","trans","P_Plate_Legal")
                         VALUES
                         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

    $sth->execute(array($make, $model, $badge, $price, $trans, $ppl));

    header("Location: ../Carsales_Network.php");


}



catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


?>
```